# Datatable initialization is happening twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable which is responsive as shown below :

```
<table class="table table-hover responsive datatable" data-scroll=".oc-  scroll" id="example">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>Actions</th>                           
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th></th>                           
    </tr>
  </tfoot>   
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>Edit</th>                           
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>Edit</th>                           
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>Edit</th>                           
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>Edit</th>                           
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

I have applied a column filter to the datatable using the below js

```
var tableID = "example";
var colIdxIgnore = "6";

if(tableID != '') {

    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#' + tableID + ' tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#' + tableID + ' thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        if ($(this).index() != colIdxIgnore) {
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        }
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#' + tableID).DataTable();
    // Apply the search
    if(table.columns().eq(0) != null){
        table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {         
            $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                table
                    .column( colIdx )
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            } );
        } );
    }
  table.destroy();

}
```

And there is another js file which also initializes the datatable again. Here is the link to the that js file - [js file]http://208.68.38.122/themes/emerald/dev/javascripts/application.js

Now if I have a datatable with more than 12-15 columns and open the datatable page in the browser, some of the columns will be hidden, which is expected. If I click on a row, that hidden columns will be shown. But because of double initialization of datatable, the hidden columns are displayed twice as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: Datatable hidden columns issue]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to initialize the table twice

Comment: The default application.js file is intializing once. Then in the columnfilterjs file I'm using/recreating the Datatable (var table = $('#' + tableID).DataTable();) which is why it is initializing twice.

Comment: initializing the same datatable on different calls is not a good idea it will affect the performance . Use the already initialized datatable object for search

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have any idea on that. Can you please help me with that ? The first initialization is done by column filter and then in application.js file.

Comment: dude your application.js file is minimized version

Comment: If you don't mind can you beautify it using this online tool - http://jsbeautifier.org/

This is a very big file so I couldn't send it to you.